# how to call a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function called `monitoring()` as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/mvNqt/). My question here is, if i would like to call that function, can I simply do this?

```
$('#status_table #monitor_'+rowID).change(monitoring(rowID));
```

My logic is that, when the status of the checkboxes(`#monitor_'+rowID`is the checkbox ID) are changed, the function will be called.

As i would like to find out whether the function is being called, i do an append as follow:

```
$('#test').append(fbType + fbNum);
```

But it does not show up anything for fbType and fbNum in the div #test. 
Can someone point to me how i should call the function or correct my mistakes in that code/logic?

Comment: and you cant pass parameters with reference so you gotta think of a work around that structure

Answer (score 2):

`change` expects a *reference* to a function, whereas you're currently *calling* it and using its return value as the argument to `change`–not what you want, since it doesn't return a function.

One option is to create a function generator that takes the row ID and use the return value as the argument to `change`, roughly:

```
function createMonitor(rowId) {
    return function() {
        // Do something with rowId
    };
};

$('#status_table #monitor_'+rowID).change(createMonitor(rowID));
```

Without knowing where `rowID` is coming from it's difficult to know if this is the best approach.

Comment: thank you. even i do not know where exactly the problem lies actually, as i will have multi rows in the table and each row has a checkbox with different ID. :( it is way too complicated for a beginner like me. i'm sorry if i post stupid questions... please correct me wherever i'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code will `call` the function `monitoring` and *bind its return value as the event handler*, which is probably not what you need.

You can instead do it like:

```
$('#status_table #monitor_'+rowID).change(function() {
    monitoring(rowID);
});
```

Comment: i tried that previously but it doesn't work...(updated my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/yvonnezoe/rDKfR/) :( not sure if it is because of other parts in the function monitoring() itself?

Answer (score 0):

Ah the power of closures:

```
$('#status_table #monitor_'+rowID).change(function() { monitoring(rowID) });
```

There will be a little more to it than this, as you probably need to actually pass in rowID somewhere; looking at your fiddle, it seemed at first glance as though you'd want to have this snippet inside the function `addText`, where you calculate a rowID.

Corrected fiddle (with rowID being utilized):
http://jsfiddle.net/EVW4S/

Seems like there are more problems with this code...
One tip that might help in debugging: `console.debug` is useful (rather than using `alert()` or changing content)

Comment: yes i tried that but it will be impractical because it will only "monitor" the status when the same type and number is selected (button "Add" is pressed) again.

Comment: As it stands right now, this line in your fiddle only executes once, on page load, before *any* rowID is calculated. (Unless I am missing something).

Comment: hmmm... i see, that's why there is nothing appended into div #test? sorry i'm a bit noob at this and do not know how exactly is the flow of program... please correct me

Answer (score 0):

Create a button somewhere to trigger the function then. You can have a better control over the function as well.